# Emmet shortcut in VS Code

Tags: html, shortcut, emmet

I've been searching for a while but I can't see any solution to my issue. I have installed emmet for VS Code and when trying shortcuts not all the tags are correct?

! as below:

html(lang="en")
head
meta(charset="UTF-8")
meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
title Document
body

as you can see it's missing opening / closing tags

ul>li*5 as below:

ul
li
li
li
li
li

It's driving me crazy! Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like pug/jade, not html. Is there a setting that dictates which type of html is output?

Comment: this is what's in my json file:

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "vue-html": "html",
        "razor": "html",
        "plaintext": "jade"
    },

I'm new to using plugins on VS Code so i'm a bit stumped?

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but either remove the "plaintext" key and value of that config, or try saving the file as an HTML file before running the emmet shortcuts.

Comment: That's solved it - thank you! Just a school boy error! I wasn't saving the file before running the emmet shortcuts. Good lesson learnt so thank you!